# Ajax não funciona, selectOneMenu em cascata

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

estou desenvolvendo um programa porém o ajax não funciona de jeito nenhum. Resolvi fazer um sistema bem simples para ver onde esta o erro e mesmo assim não consigo uma solução. Vi alguns erros desse no fórum porem não consegui também.
HTML

```
        <h:outputText value="Pais: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="comboPais" process="@this" converter="conversorObjetoId" value="#{comboMB.pais}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Selecione--" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{comboMB.paises}" var="pais" itemLabel="#{pais.nome}" itemValue="#{pais}" />
            <p:ajax event="change" update="comboEstados" actionListener="#{comboMB.buscar()}" />            </p:selectOneMenu>

        <h:outputText value="Estados: " />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="comboEstados" value="#{vendasMB.estado}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Selecione--" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{vendasMB.estados}" var="estado"  itemLabel="#{estado.nome}" itemValue="#{estado}" />    
                </p:selectOneMenu>      </h:panelGrid>      </p:panel> </h:form>
```

O index eu mudei varias coisas ja deixei onChange, ja tirei update, listener varias tentativas

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    paises = dao.consultarPais();
    System.out.println("--> init*()");
}

public void buscar(ActionEvent event) {
    estados = dao.consultarEstados(pais);
}
```

ATUALIZADO

```
    <h:form id="frmTeste">
<p:outputPanel id="cadastroCidades">
        <h:panelGrid id="painel" columns="2">

            <p:outputLabel for="comboPaises" value="Pais: " />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="comboPaises" converter="conversorObjetoId"  value="#{comboMB.pais}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Selecione--" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{comboMB.paises}" var="pais" itemLabel="#{pais.nome}" itemValue="#{pais}" />
                <p:ajax listener="#{comboMB.buscar}" update="comboEstados" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel for="comboEstados"   value="Estados: " />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="comboEstados" converter="conversorObjetoId"  value="#{vendasMB.estado}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Selecione--" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{vendasMB.estados}" var="estado"  itemLabel="#{estado.nome}" itemValue="#{estado}" />    
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Se puder, experimente usar o ajax do JSF, o `f:ajax` ao invés do `p:ajax`.

Comment: Opa mano, ja tentei essa opção.

Comment: Já tentou tirar o parâmetro do método buscar do teu Bean. E fazer a consulta do dao usando getPais() como parâmetro de busca ? Sendo que esse getPais() é o o objeto setado no value do selectOneMenu ao ele ser processado após a mudança de valor do select

Comment: Ele chega a chamar o buscar do bean?

Comment: 2 opções pra você: Coloque os componentes do comboEstado em um `panelGrid` e mande atualizar o mesmo. No seu ajax, tem que ter o `event="change"`. Deixe seu método sem parâmetros e adicione um `process="@form"` no seu comboPaises.

Comment: Tentou <p:ajax event="change" update="comboEstados" listener="#{comboMB.buscar}" /> e mudar no bean para public void buscar() ?

Comment: Bom dia desculpa a demora, Marcus ele nao chama o buscar no bean.

Comment: @Douglas fiz outro panelGrid, coloquei event, tirei os parâmetros e coloquei o process no selectOneMenu do 'comboPaises'

Comment: @MarcusMartins sim , ja fiz isso ai tambem.

Comment: @Paulo irei tentar essa opção e logo mais dou resposta.

Comment: Bom... então testa o seguinte: tira o listener do p:ajax, deixa somente o update. No bean, coloca o buscar() dentro do método de setPais(). Nesse caso, toda vez que ele setar o pais, vai fazer o update no estados.

Comment: @MarcusMartins testei essa opção agora e nada.

Comment: Mas ele ao menos setou o país? Ou ele nem está chamando o setPais?

Comment: ele nem esta chamando o setPais.

Comment: Pessoal coloquei o Serializable nas entidades Pais e Estado e agora ele chama o ajax,

Comment: Resolveu então @RodrigoCosta?

Comment: RESOLVIDO ! OBRIGADO A TODOS.